# Could we have a 'random question' function?

Tags: feature-request

I'm familiar with the recent catalogue of questions here and find it a little cumbersome to search through the library for especially interesting questions I haven't seen yet. Sometimes the related questions links are pure gold. But I have a feeling there are gaps in what I find that way, and anyhow, frankly they can be a little too distracting. I end up opening a tab for each one and then open more tabs from the new ones I've opened and soon I'm in a tangle and end up closing several unread because I'm trying to get focused again.

What would be more digestible for me would be a nice, neat 'random question' tab I can click and browse down in order until I find something that grabs me.

Comment: It's only once a week. And i have to go open it to get to those questions, that isn't usually what i'm after when i read it.

Comment: Hah! That's awesome!

Comment: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4856/laplace-method-for-orbit-estimation Damn you, diceStack, you've got me reading papers featuring symbols in little pointy hats, smiley faces, & arrows over their heads . . .